# Customizing WP FlexSlider plugin - changing way slider images are cropped

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, image

I've managed to remove the the side (prev/next) panels of the FlexSlider, however now the primary image is distorted. I'm wondering if there is a way to have the featured image cropped true to proportion/scale? I've tried adjusting the size of the slider, but the problem I'm running into is I won't have control over what images are used - square, rectangle, horizontal, vertical, etc.

The test site can be viewed [here](http://thelocalrose.com/new/).

The CSS I've used is

```
#featured-slider li .featured-thumb img {
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
  height:400px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  opacity:0.6;
  transition:opacity 0.5s;
  width:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either you change your height to : 600px and above or you just find image that have saiz 960X400 that fix the vassel